# Lazy attoparsec parser for log files

Tags: performance, parsing, haskell

I've written a parser with the help of some experienced Haskellers. The parser is not bad, but the same kind of parser written in PHP7 with regular expressions is much faster (takes 25% of the time that takes the Haskell one).

This is a subset of the file I want to parse: [lpaste link](http://lpaste.net/144719)

The main objective of the parser is to get three kinds of errors:

1) Error with backtrace (multiple lines, the first of them is like 3))
2) Single error with one more line
3) Single line error

Here is my current code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8 hiding (lines, filter, unlines, head, readFile, take, length,
                                           putStrLn, tail, map, concat, or, writeFile, intersperse,
                                           groupBy, hGetContents)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TIO
import Data.Attoparsec.Text.Lazy hiding (take)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (replicateM, mapM, forM, forM_)
import Data.Either (either)
import Data.List (intersperse, groupBy)
import System.Environment
import qualified System.IO as SIO

data TimeStamp = MkTimeStamp T.Text
               deriving Show

data LogFileInfo = BackTraceLineInfo T.Text
                 | BackTraceInfo TimeStamp T.Text T.Text [LogFileInfo]
                 | Error TimeStamp T.Text
                 | LargeError TimeStamp T.Text T.Text
                 deriving Show

data LineType = SingleLineError TimeStamp T.Text
              | DirectoryInfo T.Text
              | ErrorInfo T.Text
              | LineBackTraceInfo T.Text
              | BackTraceString T.Text
              | BackTraceLine T.Text
              deriving Show

parseTimeStamp :: Parser TimeStamp
parseTimeStamp = do
  year <- many digit
  char '-'
  month <- many digit
  char '-'
  day <- many digit
  char ' '
  hour <- many digit
  char ':'
  minute <- many digit
  char ':'
  second <- many digit
  char ' '
  (return . MkTimeStamp) $ T.pack $ year ++ "-" ++ month ++ "-" ++ day ++ " " ++ hour ++ ":" ++ minute ++ ":" ++ second

parseError :: Parser LineType
parseError = do
  string $ "ERROR - "
  timeStamp <- parseTimeStamp
  errorInfo <- parseAnyLine
  return $ SingleLineError timeStamp errorInfo

parseDirectoryInfo :: Parser LineType
parseDirectoryInfo = do
  char '/'
  directoryInfo <- parseAnyLine
  (return . DirectoryInfo) $ T.append "/" directoryInfo

parseErrorInfo :: Parser LineType
parseErrorInfo = do
  errorInfo <- parseAnyLine
  (return . ErrorInfo) errorInfo

parseBackTraceString :: Parser LineType
parseBackTraceString = do
  let backTraceStr = " Backtrace: "
  string backTraceStr
  return $ BackTraceString $ T.fromStrict backTraceStr

parseBacktraceLine :: Parser LineType
parseBacktraceLine = do
  char '#'
  number <- many1 digit
  backTraceInfo <- parseAnyLine
  let numberPart = '#' : number
  return $ LineBackTraceInfo $ T.append (T.pack numberPart) backTraceInfo

parseAnyLine :: Parser T.Text
parseAnyLine = do
  lineStr <- many anyChar
  return $ T.pack lineStr

-- Skips n lines for allowing other parsers to succeed
skipNLines n = replicateM n $ manyTill anyChar endOfLine

-- performParser :: Parser a -> T.Text -> BackTraceInfo
performParser = parseOnly

getEitherRight :: Either a b -> b
getEitherRight (Right b) = b

-- try no sirve con attoparsec
parseLogLine :: Parser LineType
parseLogLine = parseError
           <|> parseDirectoryInfo
           <|> parseBacktraceLine
           <|> parseBackTraceString
           <|> parseErrorInfo

main = do
  (fileName : _) <- getArgs
  h <- SIO.openFile fileName SIO.ReadMode
  SIO.hSetEncoding h SIO.latin1
  fileContents <- SIO.hGetContents h
  let titleLength           = length fileName
      titleWithoutExtension = take (titleLength - 4) fileName
      allNonEmptyLines      = map (T.pack) $ tail $ filter (/= "") $ lines fileContents -- [T.Text]
      stringList = fmap (\x -> case eitherResult (parse parseLogLine x) of
                                 Left e  -> return $ show e
                                 Right a -> return $ show a) allNonEmptyLines
  -- TODO: list processing
  h <- SIO.openFile "errorSummary.txt" SIO.WriteMode
  forM_ stringList (\x -> hPutStrLn h $ B8.pack $ unlines x)
  SIO.hClose h
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of my code?? (preferably with attoparsec, but regular expressions are allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some points:

- You are reading file as `String` and then turn it into `Text`.
  Reading file directly into `Text` using `Data.Text.IO` module is much
  faster. If your logs contain only ASCII characters consider using
  `ByteString` instead of `Text`.
- You are actually parsing file twice: first when filtering out empty
  lines and second in attoparsec parser itself. Handling empty lines
  withing attoparsec should give you some improvement.
- Attoparsec documentation advises using `Text`-oriented parsers
  whenever possible. For you this means replacing

  ```
  year <- many digit
  char '-'
  ```

  with `takeTill (=='-')`, for example. This would also eliminate
  packing and concatenation of `String`s.

Finally, you can play around with [GHC's profiler](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) to see if it can give you useful insights on where performance bottlenecks are.

Comment: I will wait to implement your changes and see the results and then I may accept your answer. Sorry but I'm very busy in my job.

Comment: The main problem was the function **parseAnyLine**, which I've changed to **takeText**, my old code takes 155 secs and the new one 34 secs, so I think is a incredible speed up :D, thanks bro.